# UDM_DISPUTE: Templates don't load first time

Tags: sap-erp

I've created a few templates for dispute management (`UDM_DISPUTE`) and I want to create new documents with them for cases. The first time I load the transaction, the templates don't exist. Then I want to create a new document from a template like this:

STEPS:

1. Select a case
2. Open the Linked Objects tab
3. Right-click various folder
4. Select Create
5. Select Create with template

The first time it says there are no templates, but if I select the case again after that and try it again, it works.

Any idea why this happens?

**STEP 1**

[image: img 1]

**STEP 2**

[image: img 2]